# Как увеличить кластеры с сохранением разницы?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Как сделать на Яндекс Картах кластеры зависимыми от числа точек в них и при этом крупнее?
`clusterIconPieChartRadius` меняет размер, но при этом делает все кластеры одинаковыми.

Пример, как из-за `clusterIconPieChartRadius` теряется разница размера кластеров: https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/clusterer_pie_chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример линейного увеличения размера:

```
clusterIconPieChartRadius:    function clusterSize(node:any, ) {   
    for (var radius = 0, i = 0, r = node.length; i < r; i++)
        radius += node[i].weight;
    return 20 + radius;
},
```